# Sql server authentication Issue

Tags: sql-server-2005

In sql server 2005,

I could not connect to  sql server in 'sql server Authentication' mode but i could connect in windows authentication mode.

The Username and password are also correct.

The Error says:

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occured during the login process.(provider: shared memory provider, error:0-No process is on the other end of the pipe) (microsoft sql server: error:233)

Comment: what error are you getting displayed / in the logs?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the SQL Server credentials in SQL authentication mode and not your windows creds?

Comment: You probably need to change the authentication type set in the properties of the server.  Sounds like your not using mixed mode. here is a link that should help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx

Comment: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occured during the login process.(provider: shared memory provider, error:0-No process is on the other end of the pipe) (microsoft sql server: error:233)

Answer (score 0):

May be the server is not configured to use both windows and sql server authentication modes